# PHP (or perhaps MySQL) Locks

Tags: php, mysql, synchronization, locking

I have an application that:

- Calls a PHP script on a server.
- PHP script makes a MySQL request that returns a row in the MySQL table if a particular value in the row is set to false.
- PHP script modifies the row and sets the value to true.

However, I imagine in a multiprocessor server, the script could hypothetically be executing concurrently on two cores; thus, there could be a problem with both scripts attempting to access the same row in the table, even though it should ideally only be available to one of the scripts.

I suppose my question is, is there any way I can create a lock on a particular row, so that it is only accessible by one instance of the PHP script at a time? Thank you!

Comment: I am having a hard time putting into words how much of a non-issue concurrent *read* operations are. Even concurrent writes are barely within the scope of "worry" these days [within the context of mySQL, at least] unless you're processing many *thousands* of operations concurrently. Take my advice and do not lose any sleep [or write any code] for this.

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour of MySQL might be enough to solve your problems:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/internal-locking.html

Answer (score 0):

Simply use transactions.

```
BEGIN WORK;
...sql statements...
COMMIT;
```

If you are using MyISAM you can use `LOCK TABLES`, but it is inefficient as it locks the whole table, not just a set of rows.